# "Cannot read properties of undefined" React Jest Async Axios error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, axios, jestjs

Cannot get past mocking the return value of an async axios call. I continuously get the error of "Cannot read properties of undefined". There are very similar questions and articles I have found, but unfortunately no 1:1 solution.

Here is the relevant source code: `

```
...
async function getJWTToken() {
    const result = await axios({method: "get", url: '<url hidden for stack overflow>'});
    setCookie('jwttoken', result.data, { path: '/' });
  }`

  <Box component="div" sx={{ marginTop: '30px' }}>
            <Button 
                 onClick={getJWTToken}
                 variant="contained">
                  Get JWT Token
            </Button>
         </Box>
...
```

Here is the test:

```
import { fireEvent, queryByAttribute, render, waitFor} from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import App from '../../components/App';
import axios from 'axios';
// Mock jest and set the type
jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>
const renderComponent = () => (render(<App />));

describe("Get JWT Token Mock with Button Click", () => {
     test("Get JWT Token Mock with Button Click", async () => {
        const { getByText } = renderComponent();

        mockedAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
          data: "JWT token"
        })
      );
    
       fireEvent.click(getByText('Get JWT Token')); 
       });
});
```

Here is the error:

```
  RUNS  src/__tests__/integration/App.test.tsx
/Users/ali/Documents/code/rtm-test-web-app/src/components/App.tsx:290
    setCookie('jwttoken', result.data, {
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at getJWTToken (/Users/ali/Documents/code/rtm-test-web-app/src/components/App.tsx:290:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It dealt with the strange distinction of the syntax.

I changed it to jest.MockedFunction instead of Mocked and then did not specify get in the implementation of MockedFunction.

Changes: `

```
jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios>
...
mockedAxios.mockResolvedValueOnce({
            data: "JWT Token",
          })`
```